# $\operatorname{tg}2x=-1$ find $x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\operatorname{tg}2x=-1$

$x∈[\pi/2,\pi]$

I tried expressing $\operatorname{tg}2x=\sin2x/\cos2x$ but is there any elegant other method?

Comment: Can you solve $\tan \theta = -1$ for $\theta$? And can you solve $\theta = 2x$ for $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the reference angle (first quadrant) by ignoring the sign of the tangent first. Let $y=2x$.

$\tan y = 1 \implies y =\frac{\pi} 4$

Since the tangent is negative the angle can be either in the second quadrant ($\pi - y$) or fourth quadrant ($2\pi - y$).

So we get $2x = \frac{3\pi}4$ or $2x = \frac{7\pi}4$.

giving $x = \frac{3\pi}8$ or $x = \frac{7\pi}8$.

and only the latter value lies in the required range.

So $x = \frac{7\pi}8$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $\tan\frac\pi 4=1 $, so  $\tan\bigl(-\frac\pi 4\bigr)=-1 $, as it is an odd function. Furthermore, the function has period $\pi$, hence
$$\tan 2x=-1\iff 2x\equiv -\frac\pi 4\mod\pi\iff x\equiv -\frac\pi 8\mod\frac\pi 2.$$